# Import Contribution Fails - Financial Type

Tags: civicontribute

Trying to import contributions. The data file has integer for Financial Type. Import fails Error File says: "Financial Type is not valid: 1"

Everything I have read said to enter the Financial Type Id. My data table for Financial Type has IDs 1,2,3,4,5
How can 1 not be valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We’ve hit this too in the past -> solution is to use the Name of the Financial Type. eg Donation (instead of 1). PS - Also match the case.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and the problem was solved. Contrary to the documentation, the Financial Type is the Financial Type Name not the Financial Type ID. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly - glad it helped you out.

Comment: @BenBachrach - if you've found a bug in the documentation would be great if you can submit an update for that.

Comment: I think it’s even _id in the header of that column in the import_errors csv file

Comment: @Aidan - where do we submit updates for the documentation?

Comment: @BenBachrach - depends which documentation we're talking about!  What's the URL for the documentation you're looking at?  If it's https://docs.civicrm.org/user/... then there is a pencil icon to the right of the main header.  Click that and make your edits and follow the prompts to submit an update.

Comment: @Aidan - I made proposed revision and submitted it by making a pull request.

Comment: The key issue may be that this was likely an unintentional side-effect of other core edits; i.e. the docs may be right and id should work